# Detecting when a View has been invalidated

Tags: android, view

In a custom View, I need to perform some additional work inside onDraw() if and only if the View was invalidated by the application; that is, my own code called `invalidate()` in the UI thread or `postInvalidate()` in a non-UI thread. If on the other hand `onDraw()` is being called because the system invalidated the View, I don't wish that additional work to be performed.

What's the best way to achieve this? My immediate thought is to simply override `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` and set a flag in both of those, but it would be nicer if there was a single UI-thread method I could override.

Any thoughts please?

Thanks, Trev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

postInvalidate() ends up calling invalidate() so you don't need to override both. But if you override invalidate(), the system will call the overridden version.

Comment: Ah, splendid. Thanks once again, Romain!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that without extending view class.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw() {
            //View was invalidated
        }
    });
```